# How to declare char sequence for function (C++)?

Tags: c++

How to make declaration for function to have char sequence in the result?

I have this now:

```
#define _MAX_PATH   260    
char * GetTempFileName(char fileName [_MAX_PATH]);
```

But the result should be in type char [_MAX_PATH]

---

```
#include <array>
typedef std::array<char,_MAX_PATH> Path;
extern class Setts
{
    char path [_MAX_PATH];

public:
    Setts();~Setts();
    Path getTempFileName(const Path &fileName);
} setts;

Setts::~Setts(){}

Path Setts::getTempFileName(const Path &fileName) 
{
    GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, path);
    strcat(path, "\\");
    strcat(path, fileName);
    return path;
}
```

This is what makes problem to me...

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'Setts::GetTempFileNameA'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2556: 'int Setts::GetTempFileNameA(Setts::Path)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'Setts::Path Setts::GetTempFileNameA(Setts::Path)'
```

---

Is it really not possible to get the result in char sequence char [_MAX_PATH] ? The problem here is, that when I create new type Path, so all functions of conditions that depends on char [_MAX_PATH] type cause errors in the project.

---

From comments with g-makulik

> What does mean the path.data() ... data looks like some function, what
>   does this do? Is it evaluated after the result of the function is
>   saved to path variable?  – user1141649 16 mins ago

g-makulik:

```
It provides access to the std::array's underlying data (an array of char[260]). You can use it in other places to interface that array as well. –
```

---

I tried to simplify it because compatibility with the rest of the project:

```
settings.h:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
typedef char Path [_MAX_PATH]; 

extern class Setts
{
    Path& path;

public:
    Setts();~Setts();

    Path& getTempFileName(const Path &fileName);
    bool load();

    Path& BasePath;
    Path& ScenPath;

    Path& TempPath;
    #define DEL_TEMP_ON_EXIT 1;

    Path& logname;

    bool intense;

} setts;
```

settings.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "settings.h"
#include <stdio.h>

Setts::~Setts(){}

Path& Setts::getTempFileName(const Path &fileName) 
{
    GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, path);
    strcat(path, "\\");
    strcat(path, fileName);
    return path;
}

bool Setts::load()
{
    TempPath = getTempFileName("scendata.tmp");
    logname = getTempFileName("ats_cache.log");

    return (result == ERROR_SUCCESS);
}
```

Now I got error: `near TempPath = getTempFileName("scendata.tmp");` and `logname = getTempFileName("ats_cache.log");` :

'Setts::getTempFileName' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'const Path (&)'
Reason: **cannot convert from 'const char [13]' to 'const Path'**
There is no context in which this conversion is possible
error C2664: 'Setts::getTempFileName' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [14]' to 'const Path (&)'
Reason: **cannot convert from 'const char [14]' to 'const Path'**
There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and be the first to say, huh? Is that supposed to be a *call* or a *declaration* ??

Comment: Since you've placed the typedef for `Path` inside of class `Setts` you''ll need to preceed it with classname for usage: `Setts::Path`

Comment: Also you should use the `Path` type internally for the `path` member.

Comment: OK, I found the mistake. I have to move the typedef from outside of the class. And place it after #include. But now I have next error: error C2664: 'GetCurrentDirectoryA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'Path' to 'LPSTR'

Comment: Use a different name for your function `GetTempFileName` Stupit windows defines a macro for it expanding to `GetTempFileNameA`.

Comment: OK, this helped to remove one error. But I got many errors now because type incompatibility in the rest of project. See this: http://tinyurl.com/m39rr93
The original project used char[_MAX_PATH] to define 260 chars of the path strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Thanks to all involved. (I have removed the class just for simplification here.

```
#define _MAX_PATH   260    
char path [_MAX_PATH];
char BasePath [_MAX_PATH];
char ScenPath [_MAX_PATH];
char TempPath [_MAX_PATH];
char logname [_MAX_PATH];

char* getTempFileName(char *fileName, char *targetVariable);

char* getTempFileName(char *fileName, char *targetVariable) 
{
GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, targetVariable);
strcat_s(targetVariable, _MAX_PATH, "\\");
strcat_s(targetVariable, _MAX_PATH, fileName);
return targetVariable;
}

getTempFileName("scendata.tmp",TempPath);
getTempFileName("ats_cache.log",logname);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and a simple `struct`. All of them are useful.

```
typedef std::string                Path;  // or
typedef std::array<char, MAX_PATH> Path;  // or
typedef std::vector<char>          Path;

Path GetTempFileName(const Path &path);
```

or simply:

```
struct Path
{
   char value[MAX_PATH];
};
```

---

C++11 presents `using` as an alternative for `typedef`:

```
using Path = std::string;                 // or
using Path = std::array<char, MAX_PATH>;  // or
using Path = std::vector<char>;
```

Comment: Maybe I am incapable to search in google but I cannot find msdn page for std class. It's not clear to me how to include std::array in the project. + I got error C2873: 'Path' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration + I cannot access http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/ page in this moment. Strange...

Comment: The `using identifier = type_name` syntax requires C++11 I think... doesn't it?

Comment: @dreamlax: Yes. It's C++11's alternative for `typedef`.

Comment: I compile in Visual Studio Express 2010 (idk the version of C++)

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support C++11, you can use other suggestion such as `string`, `vector` and that `struct`. Also use `typedef` instead of `using`.

Comment: Oh, thanks for explanation, but I still got error missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (you can see my updated question to see more errors)

Answer (score 2):

I c++ you should better do:

```
#include <array>

typedef std::array<char,260> Path;

Path MyTempFileName(const Path& fileName);
```

---

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
#include <array>
class Setts
{

public:
    Setts();~Setts();
    typedef std::array<char,_MAX_PATH> Path;
    Path& MyTempFileName(Path fileName);

private:
    Path path;  //Path to INI
};

Setts::~Setts(){}

Setts::Path& Setts::MyTempFileName(Setts::Path fileName) 
{
    GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, path.data());
    strcat(path.data(), "\\");
    strcat(path.data(), fileName);
    return path;
}
```

But I'd say using `std::string` to keep the data, and `std::ostringstream` to format it would be a better solution for your use case than fixed size arrays.

Comment: `typedef std::array<char,MAX_PATH> Path;`

Comment: But do I really need to include all methods of the class array when I want only to define one type?

Comment: Sorry, but I am still having problems to make it working. Which tag  should I use to get code pasted here? [CODE]test.. wait[/CODE] {CODE}test.. wait{/CODE} <CODE>test.. wait</CODE> i would like to test the code, but idk how...

Comment: Simply indent four blanks and leave at least one blank line from plain text before (there's a help button in the editor also)

Comment: What does mean the path.data() ... data looks like some function, what does this do? Is it evaluated after the result of the function is saved to path variable?

Comment: It provides access to the `std::array`'s underlying data (an array of `char[260]`). You can use it in other places to interface that array as well.

Comment: This is good advise, I must add it to the post to remember it. But why not simplify all by this type: ```typedef char Path [_MAX_PATH];``` This makes much less errors. First error is function returns array in ```Path Setts::getTempFileName(const Path &fileName)``` But I could try to use .data() to access the string.

Comment: `std::array<char,260>` provides a lot more than just a simple `char[250]`, take a look at the documentation. [tag:c++] is different from [tag:c] in many ways and best practices.

Comment: Why I got error function returns array? ```Path Setts::getTempFileName(const Path &fileName) 
{
 GetCurrentDirectory(_MAX_PATH, path);
 strcat(path, "\\");
 strcat(path, fileName);
 return path;
}``` with use of ```typedef char Path [_MAX_PATH]; ```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in C, you would provide the output buffer to the function as well as the size of it. Also, assuming fileName is zero-terminated, there is no need to specify the size of the buffer.

```
char * GetTempFileName(const char *fileName, char *tempFileName, size_t tempFileNameSize);
```

The function should return the tempFileName pointer or NULL in case of an error.
You would then call it like:

```
char fileName[] = "myFile.txt";
char tempFileName[_MAX_PATH];
if (GetTempFileName(fileName, tempFileName, sizeof(tempFileName)) == NULL) {
   // handle error
}
```

I'm also assuming the implementation of GetTempFileName will use the fileName parameter as some form of template.